# Resize video in mobile mode in wordpress using php file

Tags: php, html, wordpress, video, mobile

```
<div class="container" style="text-align: center"><iframe width="100%" height="450" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6c7Fx2PR9Dk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

I inserted the above code into frontpage.php on wordpress to add an embedded youtube video. However I want to edit the height of the video player when the website is viewed from mobile mode. I tried adding .container {height: 250px !important;} in the media query but that doesn't change anything. I want to know how to either change the container size so that I can set the height to auto or add code to the media query to change the video player size. This website can be viewed at beautyinstitute.us

I also tried

```
@media screen and (max-width: 799px) {
 .container .iframe{height:250px !important;}}
```

in the responsive.css

Comment: The iframe is what you need to change the height of, not the container.

Comment: i tried editing the iframe as well

Comment: tried how? show more of your code.

Answer (score 1):

The iframe is an html element, not a class.  So targeting it like

```
.iframe
```

won't work.  Try this:

```
.container iframe {height: 250px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress can retrieve width/height of your video and generate iframe code.

```
<?php
echo apply_filter('the_content', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6c7Fx2PR9Dk');
?>
```

If you want responsive video, try [Fitvids.js](http://fitvidsjs.com/), a jQuery plugin.